# Problem when installing python-lldb-5.0

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, python, dpkg

I have been attempting to install LLVM-5 on my Ubuntu Xenial computer. There seem to be trouble installing just one python package.

```
sudo apt-get -f install


(Reading database ... 447083 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-lldb-5.0_1%3a5.0.1~svn324026-1~exp1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-lldb-5.0 (1:5.0.1~svn324026-1~exp1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-lldb-5.0_1%3a5.0.1~svn324026-1~exp1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lldb', which is also in package python-lldb-4.0 1:4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04.2
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-lldb-5.0_1%3a5.0.1~svn324026-1~exp1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The 5.0 package is not an Ubuntu package. You obtained it from someplace else. The system is trying to tell you that the 4.0 and (that non-Ubuntu) 5.0 package *conflict*. Try using the Ubuntu 5.0 package. Do you really need both 4.0 *and* 5.0?

Comment: I figured that it was something along those lines, no I do not think that I need to 4.0 package, the question is if something breaks I I remove it..

Comment: That's a very different question. Apt has a --simulate flag so you can find out.